# React native Keyboard pushes Bottomsheet out of screen / to top

Tags: android, react-native, bottom-sheet

I am struggling with this issue now for over three weeks.
I am using the package `osdnk/react-native-reanimated-bottom-sheet` and I want to use textinputs inside the bottomsheet. The problem appears when opening the keyboard. The bottomsheet is pushed out of the screen.

There is already a github issue about this but everyone seems to get the problem solved. Except me? Also no one answers my questions there.

Steps I tried:

- Android.xml: `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`I am using expo and don't want to escape, so please don't provide solutions with the Android.xml file.
- Replaced all `flex:1` with `height:100%`
- I tried different variations with wrapping the whole Bottomsheet / Content
- Tried to create a 3rd snapping point with 100% and snap to this point as soon as an Inputfield is focused. However, this also results in the bottom sheet beeing out of the screen.
- On IOS its working fine.

My code looks like the following: (simplyfied)

```
const renderInner = () => (
    <View>
        <FormTextInput/>
    </View>)

return (
<BottomSheet
        snapPoints={['100%']}
        renderContent={renderInner}
        renderHeader={renderHeader}
        initialSnap={0}
    />
)
```

How can I fix this weird behaviour? Please provide an example. Its enough to just use an example provided inside the git-repo, clear everything inside the bottom sheet and add a simple text-input.

[image]

### SOLUTION

Your BottomSheet parent container should have the device screen height instead of height: 100%. There is no need for the `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`.

```
import BottomSheet from 'reanimated-bottom-sheet'
import { View as Container, Dimensions } from 'react-native'

const { height } = Dimensions.get('window')


const Screen = () => (
  <Container style={{ height }}>
    {/* Your screen content here */}
    <BottomSheet {...yourBottomSheetParams} />
  </Container>
)

export default Screen
```

Comment: put BottomSheet at the very bottom of render before </View>

Comment: You mean wrapping the whole BottomSheet in a View?

Comment: yes and styled to view with flex:1

Comment: if it does not work then you can add height:Dimensions.get("screen").height instead of 30%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**android:windowSoftInputMode** already available in [**EXPO**](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/0b4b044170b90b71074c7e0f52c4f41da020d8db/exponent-view-template/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml)

[Referance](https://forums.expo.io/t/how-to-set-android-windowsoftinputmode-adjustresize-in-android-manifest-file/587)

you have to Wrap BottomSheet into View with full height like this

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text,TextInput, StyleSheet, View, Dimensions } from "react-native";
import BottomSheet from "reanimated-bottom-sheet";
const height = Dimensions.get("window").height;
export default class App extends Component {
  renderInner = () => (
    <View style={{ height: height,backgroundColor:"#eee00e"}}>
    <Text>This is Bottomsheet</Text>
      <TextInput style={{ backgroundColor: "blue",color:"#FFFFFF",marginTop:30 }} />
    </View>
  );
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ height: height,backgroundColor:"red"}}>
      <BottomSheet
        snapPoints={["60%"]}
        renderContent={this.renderInner}
        // renderHeader={renderHeader}
        initialSnap={0}
      />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, thank you your answer is working.
But: android:windowSoftInputMode is not editable in expo, please adapt your comment accoringly. I already asked in EXPO-forums. There a developer mentioned, that changing the prop is not available.

Comment: then you may assign bounty if you think it is a good solution